# How to ensure Key based FIFO on XML messages through Kafka Connect

Tags: xml, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have a problem i can't quite figure out a fix for.

We're consuming messages where the sequencing is critically important from a MQ source with guaranteed FIFO.
The feed consists of delta updates for millions of entities with potentially thousands of messages a second. As a result latency is important as well.
The messages consist of XML envelopes containing a single entity delta each.

The issue we have is that the message format is very complex - so parsing it within Kafka Connect using an XLS doesn't seem feasible, because we need to retransmit it in the same format, and there doesn't seem to be a way to do that fast and consistently enough to meet our constraints.

We currently are maintaining FIFO by using a single partition and a single consumer instance for all downstream consumer groups. Which up to now has been fine, but we are hitting a point where to scale to where we need to go next we need to start going horizontally.

From what i've been researching the only way to maintain the FIFO constraint on an entity is to ensure the entity key is the partition key going into Kafka.
However the key is in XML, and as previously mentioned directly parding the XML doesn't seem feasible.

Is there a way to extract a block of XML using a regex and use that as the key - since it will contain all the compounds that make up the entity id - within kafka connect using an SMT

Example XML body

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataEnvelope xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:thread="java:java.lang.Thread" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" TimeStamp="2023-10-16T13:16:17.604Z" Version="1.432.1">
   <Originator CompanyShortName="OCR__22.76" />
   <DeliveringSystem CompanyShortName="JJMMK__Prod" />
   <Entity>
      <Identifier>
         <ProviderCompany CompanyContext="344KL">EMBg</ProviderCompany>
         <EntityNumber>776</EntityNumber>
         <OriginatorPort PortContext="STD">FLK-01d</OriginatorPort>
         <DestinationPort PortContext="EXCP">SACP-99g</DestinationPort>
         <DepartDate>2023-10-24</DepartDate>
         <AttemptNumber>1</AttemptNumber>
      </Identifier>
      <DeltaData>
         ....
      </DeltaData>
   </Entity>
</DataEnvelope>
```

i've omitted the Delta Data block because it's not relevent - but it is a n dimensional dataset that covers a wealth of data - which is the main reason why parsing is ineffient.
The key thing is that the identifier for the entity is a compound key based off that entire Identifier block.

Thank you for your help in advance.

I have tried XML translation but that has caused more issues than it solved